# Self-Learning Geometry

Tags: geometry, soft-question

I'm an undergraduate senior wondering where he should start in learning geometry. My university unfortunately offers no such course. Should i begin with riemann geometry or differential geometry and can you recommend a textbook. I have taken 2 semesters of real analysis and algebra.

Comment: What about Euclidean geometry?

Comment: Riemannian geometry is a special topic in differential geometry.

Comment: Saying that you want to learn "geometry" is almost as general as you want to study "mathematics", you could try to be more precise. However, if you never did a topology course, maybe this is the first thing you should study.

Comment: I apologize for it being so general. I have never had a course on geometry so I did not know what to specify. I did have a chance to talk to a professor today and he said for topology what was taught in real analysis is enough (through connectedness and compactness) but gave no advice on geometry since our school has no geometers

Answer (score 1):

With the courses you have done, you will be able to do differential geometry and then learn topology along side it.

There are many resources avaliable to your disposal on OpenCourseWare, sponsored by MIT.

Comment: Thank you, i'll go check them out. Should I follow the textbook they suggest in syllabi or do you have a better recommendation?

Comment: It depends on what textbook you were recommend my the course. What is the name of it?

Comment: There was a list of useful resources, but this was the textbook for the class Kuhnel, Wolfgang. Differential Geometry: Curves – Surfaces – Manifolds

Comment: That is actually a very good book. I read it! You should think about having more than one kind of textbook so that you can compare the ideas in each book and then get a better Idea of the complex concepts.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much. I just got that textbook from my school library and differentiable geometry by kreyszig

Comment: That's Great! I wish you good luck on your studies.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt differential geometry from Pressley's [Elementary Differential Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/184882890X), and I highly recommend it. It's well-written and not too terse, and has good exercises with solutions. The only real drawback is that it is mainly focused on 2 and 3 dimensions, so if what you're mostly interested in is generalising to higher dimensions, then it's probably not for you. However, understanding the material in this book would also help you in understanding generalisations to higher dimensions.